# Asp.net function not getting called

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

When the `checkboxlist1` item is selected, the function is not getting     called!!!!

I am trying to call Compute cost function when anything is selected from the checkbox and dropdown box. Please point out errors in this code as to why this is not working. I am using Visual Studio 2013 version.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public partial class Lab8_1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Variable1"] = TextBox1.Text;
        //Label1.Text = Session["Variable1"].ToString();
        Response.Redirect("Lab8_2.aspx");
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Total"] = Total.Text;
        Total.Text = Session["Total"].ToString();
        Response.Redirect("Lab8_2.aspx");
    }
    protected void CheckboxList1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Compute_Item_Cost();

    }
    protected void Compute_Item_Cost()
    {

        Session["Total"] = 0;
        Session["Cart"] = "";
        foreach (ListItem listItem in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {

            if (listItem.Selected)
            {
              switch(listItem.Text)
              {
                  case "Wilson":
                      Session["Total"] = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["Total"]) + (Convert.ToDecimal(listItem.Value)*(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)));
                      break;
                  case "Slazenger":
                      Session["Total"] = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["Total"]) + (Convert.ToDecimal(listItem.Value)*(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue)));
                      break;
                  case "Babolai":
                      Session["Total"] = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["Total"]) + (Convert.ToDecimal(listItem.Value)*(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList3.SelectedValue)));
                      break;
                  case "Ihead":
                      Session["Total"] = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["Total"]) + (Convert.ToDecimal(listItem.Value)*(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList4.SelectedValue)));
                      break;
                  case "Prince":
                      Session["Total"] = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["Total"]) + (Convert.ToDecimal(listItem.Value)*(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList5.SelectedValue)));
                      break;
              }
              Total.Text = Session["Total"].ToString();
            }
        }

     }
}
```

Here is the aspx code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"   AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Lab8_1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Lab8_1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"  Runat="Server">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
<br />

<br />

<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckboxList1_SelectedValueChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="10">Wilson</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="8">Slazenger</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6">Babolai</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="12">Ihead</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="10">Prince</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br />
<asp:Label ID="Total" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<br />
```

Getting formatexception from the `String["Total"]` lines.... inside the case statement

Comment: Did you wire it up to the selection changed event in the aspx?  Can you add the aspx code?

Comment: <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Lab8_1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Lab8_1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: trying to add the aspx code but can't do it here....

Comment: edit your question and add it to the end?

Comment: Where you use `String["Total"]` ?

Comment: case "Wilson":
                        Session["Total"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Total"]) + (Convert.ToInt32(listItem.Value) * (Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)));
                        break;

Comment: sorry, Session["Total"]...

Comment: What's the exception ??

Comment: That because there is no value in your dropdown to convert into int

Comment: Thanks a lot, now trying to add the values :-)

Comment: you are welcome :) your code is messy try to simplify your code

Comment: Now it is showing the total, but when I select a different item from the dropdown list it is not able to reflect the exact multiplied total

Answer (score 0):

I can`t find SelectedValueChanged event for CheckBoxList control in asp.net.The following are CheckBoxList Events for reference link.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Should call your function from SelectedIndexChanged event.

```
protected void CheckboxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Compute_Item_Cost();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any values for dropdownlist1.

```
Session["Total"] = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["Total"]) +   (Convert.ToDecimal(listItem.Value)*(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)));
```

Try this under DropDownList1 and then choose it

```
<asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
```

Comment: I realized it and resolved the issue! Thanks for the response!